# How to use Astyle on part of file

Tags: eclipse, astyle

I'm using *Astyle* in *Eclipse*.

I want to be able to use it on a part of a file, and not on an entire source file (e.g. to beautify only one function in the code, and not the entire source file).
How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a true lacking feature, I think!

Answer (score 1):

For now, astyle [doesn't support dry runs](http://sourceforge.net/p/astyle/bugs/285/) nor [ignoring sections of a file](http://sourceforge.net/p/astyle/bugs/119/#951d).
So implementing the feature that you are wishing for would probably imply creating a temporary file and invoke astyle to format it.
Maybe you have enough eclipse knowledge to implement that.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I could use this feature inside Code::Blocks (SVN 9455) that uses Astyle for code beautification.[image: Formatting part of code using Astyle inside Code::Blocks]